# reading delimiter with fortran

Tags: fortran, delimiter

I need to read this kind of file. I have problem reading the delimiters within the file.

xxxx

dd/mm/yyyy

text

text

angle

Number of points

-13.82|654781.695|292510.337|4.889|SD

0.00|654795.515|292510.337|4.373|P1

1.25|654796.765|292510.337|4.324|SD

1.29|654796.805|292510.337|4.657|SD

1.68|654797.195|292510.337|4.622|SD

......

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried to read the delimiter "|" as a character, but it didn't work

Comment: That's not very helpful :( Could you show us some code? Maybe then we can help you!

Answer (score 2):

(1) Read lines from the file into a string using the "(a)" format.

(2) Replace unwanted delimiters in the string with delimiters recognized by Fortran (spaces or commas).

(3) Get data from the string using an "internal read".

The program below illustrates steps (2) and (3).

```
program main
implicit none
character (len=20) :: str
integer            :: i
real               :: x,y
str = "321.1|5678.9"
do i=1,len_trim(str)
   if (str(i:i) == "|") str(i:i) = " "
end do
print*,"str = '" // trim(str) // "'"  ! output: '321.1 5678.9'
read (str,*) x,y
print*,"x, y =",x,y ! output: x, y = 321.1 5678.9
end program main
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. I tried to read it as a character but it didn't work